# Are there any alternatives to the Ubuntu Terminal?

Tags: command-line

Are there any good alternatives to the Ubuntu Terminal that have special features, such as running several visible tabs at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A not entirely serious response **;)**

```
 % apropos terminal | awk '/(1)/'                       
chvt (1)             - change foreground virtual terminal
clear (1)            - clear the terminal screen
dvi2tty (1)          - preview a TeX DVI-file on an ordinary ascii terminal
g_view (1)           - View a trajectory on an X-Windows terminal
g_view_d (1)         - View a trajectory on an X-Windows terminal
gmx-view (1)         - View a trajectory on an X-Windows terminal
gnome-terminal (1)   - is a terminal emulation application.
gnome-terminal.wrapper (1) - is a terminal emulation application.
guake (1)            - A drop-down terminal for GNOME environment.
koi8rxterm (1)       - X terminal emulator for KOI8-R environments
luit (1)             - Locale and ISO 2022 support for Unicode terminals
lxterminal (1)       - a lightweight terminal emulator based on GTK+ for the LXDE desktop.
mesg (1)             - control write access to your terminal
namei (1)            - follow a pathname until a terminal point is found
open (1)             - start a program on a new virtual terminal (VT).
openvt (1)           - start a program on a new virtual terminal (VT).
reset (1)            - terminal initialization
resize (1)           - set environment and terminal settings to current xterm window size
screen (1)           - screen manager with VT100/ANSI terminal emulation
script (1)           - make typescript of terminal session
setterm (1)          - set terminal attributes
stty (1)             - change and print terminal line settings
tabs (1)             - set tabs on a terminal
terminator (1)       - Multiple GNOME terminals in one window
tmux (1)             - terminal multiplexer
tput (1)             - initialize a terminal or query terminfo database
tset (1)             - terminal initialization
tty (1)              - print the file name of the terminal connected to standard input
uxterm (1)           - X terminal emulator for Unicode (UTF-8) environments
x-terminal-emulator (1) - is a terminal emulation application.
xfce4-terminal (1)   - A Terminal emulator for X
xterm (1)            - terminal emulator for X
```

Comment: -1: a lot of these are not terminal emulators, and you miss all those that you haven't installed.

Comment: @muru the answer was not meant quite seriously. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Also, I like to use X-Term, and it is just as easy to open multiple versions, and it gives more detailed error reports

Answer (score 1):

You can actually have several tabs in Terminal!

All you have to do is press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and it will open up another tab!

This may not answer your question entirely, but I figured I would post this answer just as a heads-up in case you didn't know.

Comment: @ByteCommander Even if you've got the terminal focused?